# How to fill an array using a for loop in TypeScript, without having null elements?

Tags: typescript

I have an array which I fill using a for loop, then, I use this array to populate a drop down list in the UI, however if I loop from 2 to 11 (or any other number), the array creates the index from 0 and assigns an empty value to 0 and 1 and therefore it shows the first 2 values in the drop down as null/empty. The code is as follows:

```
MyList: number[] = [];
getList(){for(let i = 2; i<11; i++){this.MyList[i] = i;}}
```

The way it looks in the console when I print the array is as follows:

```
(11) [empty × 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

How do I get around this weird behavior?

Comment: You must have some kind of value in the first 2. What do you want them to be?

Comment: I am trying to show only numbers from 2 to 10.

Comment: I think I just answered my own question. I did the following and it works:               
 <option *ngFor="let n of MyList | slice:2:11" [ngValue]="n">{{n}} </option>                              But I am still not sure why the array in typescript works like that. I am supposed to get index 0 to 10 and 0=2, 1;3, 2:4 and so on.

Comment: I will put an answer to explain down below. Are you okay with that?

Comment: I am ok with that.

Comment: There you go, let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Because you initialize your array and putting its item only from `2`, so the first two items will be empty**

**So you would need to put items from the first index like so:**

```
MyList: number[] = [];
getList(){
  for(let i = 2; i<11; i++)
     {
       this.MyList[i - 2] = i;   // <-- minus 2 here to start from zero index
     }
}
```

By doing this, your loop starts from 2 and you also start putting your item from i (2) minus 2 which is the first index.

**There is a more efficient way to do this:**

```
Array.from({length: 10}, (_, i) => i + 2)
```

Comment: That works as intended. Now I am able to get the elements from 2 to 10 without any null values. This is great information.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more efficient/understandable way to create your array.